# how to get json id and value to populate spinner

Tags: android, json, android-volley

I have a json array below and want to select corresponding id which is number and populate the spinner with the text, when an option is selected from spinner which is also dynamic i.e. also a json array which is displayed in Spinner and send the id to the server, any help please guzs

```js
{
    "status": "success",
    "message": "banks Fetched",
    "data": {
        "214": "FIRST CITY MONUMENT BANK PLC",
        "215": "UNITY BANK PLC",
        "221": "STANBIC IBTC BANK PLC",
        "232": "STERLING BANK PLC",
        "301": "JAIZ BANK",
        "304": "Stanbic Mobile",
        "305": "PAYCOM",
        "307": "Ecobank Mobile",
        "309": "FBN MOBILE",
        "311": "Parkway",
        "315": "GTBank Mobile Money",
        "322": "ZENITH Mobile",
        "323": "ACCESS MOBILE",
        "401": "Aso Savings and Loans",
        "044": "ACCESS BANK NIGERIA",
        "014": "AFRIBANK NIGERIA PLC",
        "063": "DIAMOND BANK PLC",
        "050": "ECOBANK NIGERIA PLC",
        "084": "ENTERPRISE BANK LIMITED",
        "070": "FIDELITY BANK PLC",
        "011": "FIRST BANK PLC",
        "058": "GTBANK PLC",
        "030": "HERITAGE BANK",
        "082": "KEYSTONE BANK PLC",
        "076": "SKYE BANK PLC",
        "068": "STANDARD CHARTERED BANK NIGERIA LIMITED",
        "032": "UNION BANK OF NIGERIA PLC",
        "033": "UNITED BANK FOR AFRICA PLC",
        "035": "WEMA BANK PLC",
        "057": "ZENITH BANK PLC"
    }
}
```

Comment: simple way get json store values inside array and set array as spinner values, if you want i can show how to set spinner values

Comment: please show me, i want to use the jsonobject "data" , use the string to  populate the spinner and   sent the number to back to the server as spinner id, please help me

Comment: Which part do you need help with? Do you know how to parse a JSON String? Do you know how to populate a spinner? Both of these can be answered with a quick google search.

Answer (score 1):

So try do this using volley library:

```
private void sendjsonRequest(){

        JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest=new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET,"serverlink",null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

                String[] banks=parsejsonResponse(response);
                Spinner s = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.Spinner01);
                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, banks);
                s.setAdapter(adapter);


            }

        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        });

        requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);

    }

private String[] parsejsonResponse(JSONArray array){

        String[] banks;

         if (array!= null){
            JSONArray data=array.getJSONArray("data");

            for (int i=0;i<data.length();i++){
                try {
                      JSONObject bank=data.getJSONObject(i);

                      String id=bank.getString("id");
                      String bankname=bank.getString("bankname")

                      banks.add(bankname);

                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {

                }

            }
        }

        return banks;

    }
```

format json like this exemple:

```
[{
    "status": "success",
    "message": "banks Fetched",
    "data": [
        {
          "id": 214,
          "bankname": "FIRST CITY MONUMENT BANK PLC"
        },
        {
          "id": 215,
          "bankname": "UNITY BANK PLC"  
        },
        {
          "id": 221,
          "bankname": "STANBIC IBTC BANK PLC"
        },
        {
          "id": 232,
          "bankname": "STERLING BANK PLC"
        },
        {
          "id": 301,
          "bankname": "JAIZ BANK"
        },
        {
          "id": 304,
          "bankname": "Stanbic Mobile"
        },
        {
          "id": 305,
          "bankname": "PAYCOM"
        }
    ]
}]
```

In **oncreate** just cal **sendjsonrequest()** method

Comment: i try this in my code it give me error  "banks=parsejsonResponse(response);"                    please wot the data type of banks here

Comment: and this also give error  "JSONArray data=array.getJSONArray("data");"

Comment: the variable banks is a String [] like **parsejsonResponse()** banks I update code with data type of banks @kehindehussein

Comment: thanks it works out. please sorry this  "JSONArray data=array.getJSONArray("data");"  is given me error, help me on that pls

Comment: what is logcat error, I updated the json format too, show me the logcat error to better help you @kehindehussein

Comment: getJSONArray
(int)
in JSONArray cannot be applied
to
(java.lang.String) this is the error the  i got "JSONArray data=array.getJSONArray("data");"  at the ("data") pls help

Comment: try this JSONArray data=array.getJSONArray(0); or this JSONArray data=array.getJSONObject("data");

Comment: it give this error "Unhandled exception: org.json.JSONException"

Comment: you formated the data like the answer I updated the data structure now is na array with the values so the "JSONArray data=array.getJSONArray("data");"  dont have error, can you add the new json structure to show